# Change template dynamically from view-model (Aurelia)

Tags: aurelia

Is it possible to change which html-template is being used dynamically from the view-model?

E.g. based on data downloaded from a server, I'd like to choose different templates (or some other logic in the view-model)

**Update**
Based on the answer below suggesting `getViewStrategy`, here's a complete sample:

```
export class MultiView {
  gender : string

  getViewStrategy() {
      if(this.gender == 'boy')
          return './multi-view-blue.html'
      else
          return './multi-view-pink.html'
  }

  // when view is made visible (e.g. by using the router)
  activate() { 
      this.gender = Math.random()>0.5 ? "boy" : "girl"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do this on a single view model implement the getViewStrategy function.

```
export class MyView{
    getViewStrategy(){
        return 'my-other-view.html';        
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, had seen it before but was impossible to google it.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the documentation under [App Configuration and Startup](https://aurelia.io/docs/fundamentals/app-configuration-and-startup#customizing-conventions), titled *Configuring the View Location Convention*. Here's and excerpt:

> To do this, during bootstrap, import the `ViewLocator` and replace its `convertOriginToViewUrl` method with your own implementation.

It includes a code example you may follow as well.

---

As an alternative, you could look into the [`aurelia-compiler`](https://github.com/gooy/aurelia-compiler) library module.

> **NOTE**: This library will be refactored and parts of it will be included into the core. In the meantime it can still be used but please be aware of this breaking change.

It contains a function called [`swapView()`](https://github.com/gooy/aurelia-compiler/blob/master/src/index.js#L27) that looks like it may do what you want. An example of it being used is in the [`aurelia-dialog`](https://github.com/gooy/aurelia-dialog/blob/master/src/dialog.js#L99) library module. Hopefully you can glean some useful information from that and find a way to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for something on a single view basis, like `getViewStrategy()`. Your answer provided helpful insight though.

Answer (score 0):

Write a view-model that takes data from server and binding variables of class.

```
export class MyClass{
     constructor(){
        this.red = false;
        this.green = false;
        this.yellow = false;
        this.serverValue = "";
     }
  activate(){
    return this.bindingFunction();
  }
  bindingFunction(){ 
       if(this.serverValue == 'red') { this.red = true; }
       else if(this.serverValue == 'green') { this.green = true; }
       else this.yellow = true;
    }
 }
```

Write the view as a whole, with show.bind, and bind those with view-model.

```
<template>
        <div show.bind='red'> /* your elements */ </div>
        <div show.bind='green'> /* your elements */ </div>
        <div show.bind='yellow'> /* your elements */ </div>
 </template>
```

Comment: It's a possible solution if one doesn't want to replace the whole view with another view (just parts), as I understand. I want the view to use different HTML files based on logic, so `getViewStrategy()` does the trick.